# What is the direction of the planet if we launch a rocket from it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

If we launch a rocket from a rest planet, then what is the direction of the planet after the rocket is launched ?I guess there are 2 possible answers:

1. Move opposite the rocket because the planet is pushed by the rocket
2. Follow the rocket because the planet is attracted by the gravity of the rocket

Which one is correct?

Comment: Which one conserves momentum?

Comment: @Asher It took me a second to realize that even two gravitationally attracted bodies conserve momentum because the force they apply to each other is equal in magnitude and opposite in direction. That might've been the OP's confusion.